# Where does .net core search for certificates on linux platform

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-core, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

On Windows, for .NET Framework classes we can specify `sslkeyrepository` as *SYSTEM/*USER.On `linux` where does the .NET Core classes search for the `certificates` by default and what could be the values for `sslkeyrepository`.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/27/asp-net-core-2-1-https-improvements/ "On Linux there isn't a standard way across distros to trust the certificate, so you'll need to perform the distro specific guidance for trusting the development certificate." That should give you some hints to get started.

Comment: @LexLi: Thank you,i did go through it before posting the question.But the problem is how do we specify the location of the certificates

Comment: Ask Google what is "the distro specific guidance", and the location would be obvious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`.NET Core` uses `OpenSSL` on Linux, as a result, you need to set up your `Linux environment` in the container so that `OpenSSL` will pick up the certificate.

You can do this by two ways:

1. Copying the certificate `.crt` file to a location that `update-ca-certificates` will scan for trusted certificates - e.g. `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` oron RHEL `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/`:

   ```
    COPY myca.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
   ```
2. Invoking `update-ca-certificates`:

   ```
    RUN update-ca-certificates
   ```

Comment: Congrats on 10K

Comment: What is the content inside or the format of the certificate inside the directory  /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/?

Answer (score 8):

For Linux and Mac `.NET CORE` will use `OpenSSL`.

command to generate a private key and a certificate signing request:

```
openssl req -config https.config -new -out csr.pem
```

command to create a self-signed certificate:

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -extfile https.config -extensions v3_req -in csr.pem -signkey key.pem -out https.crt
```

command to generate a pfx file containing the certificate and the private key that you can use with Kestrel:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out https.pfx -inkey key.pem -in https.crt -password pass:<password>
```

After that `Trust the certificate`

This step is optional, but without it the browser will warn you about your site being potentially unsafe. You will see something like the following if you browser doesn’t `trust your certificate`:

There is no centralized way of trusting the a certificate on Linux so you can do one of the following:

1. Exclude the URL you are using in your browsers exclude list
2. Trust all self-signed certificates on localhost
3. Add the https.crt to the list of trusted certificates in your
   browser.

How exactly to achieve this depends on your browser/distro.

You can also reference the complete  [Kestrel HTTPS sample app](https://github.com/aspnet/samples/tree/master/samples/aspnetcore/security/KestrelHttps)

or Follow this Blog [Configuring HTTPS in ASP.NET Core across different platforms](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/11/29/configuring-https-in-asp-net-core-across-different-platforms/)

Answer (score 6):

[This page provides a good (and official) summary of the `X509Store` locations on Linux (and all platforms) for .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cross-platform-cryptography#x509store).

The short answer is that on Linux, the `LocalMachine/Root` store can be opened in ReadOnly mode, and the certificates returned from that store come from the standard Linux system-global certificate directories. @barr-j's answer provides some info on how to you can copy certificates into system directories using Linux commands. However the normal use for these system-global certificates is to specify trusted certificate authorities, NOT as a secure place to store an https certificate (which contains a private key, which shouldn't be accessible by all users on the host).

On Linux with .NET, you can't write to the `LocalMachine/Root X509Store` directly, and `LocalMachine/My` isn't supported.

If you want your certificate access limited to a specific user (a good idea for https certs), on Linux with .NET you can write to and read from a user-local cert store using `new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser)`.

Comment: Updated link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/cross-platform-cryptography