# how to configure ssl for .Net Core HttpListener in linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, ssl, httplistener

I found the document to configure https for .Net core HttpListener is only for windows. Any idea about how to configure Httplistener to use ssl in linux?

Answer (score 1):

I have put my answer in other people question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71369187/6348813

For me, the simplest way is just redirecting (proxy pass) the none ssl to ssl sites using the Nginx/Apache config file. Using this way, you don't need to re-create your ssl to match with Microsoft SSL format.